# retrieve gmail account details configured in android

Tags: android

In my application, I have to send a mail when a button is clicked. I have all details for sending the mail except the "from address". This "from address" should be the gmail account configured in the android phone. How can I fetch those details? Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It got worked by using AccountManager class.

```
AccountManager manager = AccountManager.get(this);
Account[] accounts = manager.getAccountsByType("com.google");
Account account = accounts[0];
```

We can fetch account name using

```
account.name
```

and the encrypted password using

```
manager.getPassword(account)
```

Comment: So far, this does not work. I get the following error: "java.lang.SecurityException: caller uid 10155 is different than the authenticator's uid". I don't think you can get a Google password from a 3rd party application. Please correct me if I am wrong and post a solution to this problem. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You can use the built-in `ACTION_SEND` intent to use default android's mail sending app, [here](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/how-send-email-your-application) you have an example.

This is the part you would need:

```
final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
//set the content-type
emailIntent.setType("plain/text");
//set the receivers address
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] { address.getText().toString() });
//set the subject
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject.getText());
//set the text
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, emailtext.getText());
Email.this.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));
```

Note: I haven't tested it myself

Comment: I have to send mail in the background. If I do like this, then a screen gets popped up asking for details...Anyone any idea? Have anyone used GoogleLoginServiceHelper???