# Send mail without user interactions with Intent in android

Tags: android, email, android-intent, sendmail

I want to send a mail when user clicks a button and also i should not get any interaction after that and mail should be sent automatically using email client in the mobile.

Please help me to find the solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028988/sending-email-without-user-interaction-android

Comment: i dont want to provide username and password in app,it need to get from email client

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @TGMClains if u want that there is no user interaction with the mail client in the phone then you need to create your own email client ...check out this following post.

[Sending Email in Android using JavaMail API without using the default/built-in app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-built-in-a/2033124#2033124)

Hope this solves your problem

Comment: i had checked it several times.My requirement is i need my app to integrate with default mail client and send mail automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Simply it is not possible to send the email through email client like Gmail without user interaction.

Instead of Java Mail API, I recommend you to make any Web API in PHP and code there to send the mail and call this Web API in your Android code.

Comment: Then is there possibility get the email client's email-id and password and use it in Java Mail API to send mail automatically?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4624682/retrieve-gmail-account-details-configured-in-android check it

Comment: but i don't think you will able to get password of gmail, yahoo account from third party application. because it loose the security.

Comment: so is there way to create custom email client to send mail automatically without java api?

Comment: @krishna kumar Last option i told you user earlier you have to use Java MAIL API for that.

Comment: but my problem is app should not ask user email or password,where Java Mail API does ask for username and password.

Answer (score 0):

In your `onClick()` put this :

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.parse("mailto:to@gmail.com"));
```

Comment: this too has interactions before sending mail.

Comment: @krishnakumar try this.. http://www.jondev.net/articles/Sending_Emails_without_User_Intervention_%28no_Intents%29_in_Android